# Confused with how strlen works in C

Tags: c, c-strings, strlen, pointer-arithmetic

I have been studying C lately and i have came across a source code of strlen which really confused me and i had to look it up in other places but couldnt really understand it yet.

strlen:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char* eos = str; // 1

    while (*eos++); // 2

    return (eos - str - 1); // 3
}

int main()
{
    int len = strlen("Hello");

    printf("Len: %d" , len);

    return 0;
}
```

I couldnt understand why are we using the local variable eos and why are we using it in an empty while loop and then returning that last line from the strlen function ?

Comment: Not the best implementation of `strlen` if you ask me. In short, `eos` is incremented till the `\0` terminator is found. Then the difference between it and the original pointer is returned as the length.

Comment: The while loop has ‘side effects’.  It’s short for `while (*eos) { eos++; }`.  Does that help make it more sense?  Also, `eos` probably standards for ‘end of string’.

Comment: Max, the loop you show is not the same (but actually better) than what is in the question because it won't increment eos after it finds the null terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function return type should be `size_t`.

```
size_t strlen(const char *str);
```

If two pointers point to elements of the same array then the difference between the pointer that points to the element with higher index and the pointer that points to the element with lower index yields the number of elements between the two indices.

For example if you have an array like

```
const char s[] = "12";
```

and two pointers

```
const char *p1 = &s[0];
const char *p2 = &s[1];
```

then the difference

```
p2 - p1
```

yields the value `1`.

This pointer within the original function

```
const char* eos = str;
```

will be moved across the passed string until the terminating zero character will  be found.

```
while (*eos++);
```

This loop can be rewritten like

```
while ( *eos++ != '\0' );
```

The value of the postfix expression `*esp++` is the value of the pointed character before incrementing the pointer.

So when the terminating zero is found the pointer `eos` will point to the memory after the terminating zero character and the loop stops its iterations.

Thus now the pointer `str` points to the beginning of the passed string and the pointer `eos` points to the memory just after the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

So the difference

```
(eos - str - 1)
```

gives the number of characters in the passed string that precede the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 5):

**Why is there an empty while loop?**  The loop increments `eos` until it points to the location directly after the null terminator.  The expression `*eos++` is very compact way of telling your computer to get the char value `eos` is currently pointing to, and then increment `eos` so it points at the next char.  There is no need for a body in this while loop.

**Why does it use a local variable?**  Since we are incrementing a pointer (i.e. `eos`), and we also need a pointer to the beginning of the string in the final computation (i.e. `str`), we can't simply use `str` for everything.  We need at least one other variable to get the job done.

**How does the last line work?**  The expression `eos - str` does pointer subtraction, so it calculates the distance between those two pointers and returns that as an integer.  Then we subtract 1 to make the answer correct.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer `eos` is used to advance along the string. EOS is an abbreviation for end-of-string. The `while` loop is empty because is doesn't need to do anything - because advancing the pointer is all that is needed. Once `eos` points at the null terminator, the loop exits. The last line of the function then subtracts the end pointer from the start pointer, to give the number of characters that `eos` moved past. The last `-1` is there to correct for the fact that, thanks to the post-increment operator, `eos` is always advanced one character more than it should be.

A less confusing implementation would have been:

```
int strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char* eos = str; // 1

    while (*eos)eos++; // 2

    return (eos - str); // 3
}
```

Comment: Also possible to use a `for` loop. `const char *eos; for (eos = str; *eos; eos++);`

Answer (score 1):

Strings in are character arrays terminated by what is called the null character; it's also useful to bear in mind that because there is no explicit string type in C, you need to have a pointer to the first character if you want to operate on the array of chars that you are treating as a string.

With that said, the `eos` variable is initialized to point to the beginning of the string (by equating it with `str` - remember, they are both just pointers to a char, so equating them means they point to the same thing).

Now, the 'empty' while loop has a side effect.  Because the increment (`++`) operator is used in the evaluation condition, `eos` gets incremented - and because it's a pointer, this means that with each iteration of the loop, `eos` points to successive characters.  It's basically 'walking' along the string.

This continues until the loop condition evaluates to `false`.  And in C, only the null character evaluates to false (for all possible character values; more generally, zero is false and non-zero is true).  So basically, eos will stop incrementing at the end of the string.

Now to the `return` statement.  At this point we have two variables - one called `str` that still points to the start of the string, and one called `eos` that points to the end of the string. Well - actually `eos` has spilled over because of the incrementing that was done in the loop condition. Just to be really precise here, it points to the memory address after the null character at the end of the string.

So, with a little more pointer arithmetic, if we subtract `str` from `eos` and then subtract 1 for the spilling over...well, we get the difference in the addresses of the last and first characters, which is the length of the string.

It's curious that the post-increment operator was used in the loop.  If it had been coded as `while (*++eos);`, that is using the *pre-increment* operator, then the incrementing would happen *before* evaluation of `eos` which would mean it wouldn't spill beyond the end of the string and there would be no need to subtract the extra 1 in the `return` statement.  Oh well.

Comment: Using `*++eos` would cause the loop to fail to detect a null character in the first position. A separate test would be necessary.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course - good point.